# SyntaxError when accessing column named "class" in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

I have pandas DataFrame named 'dataset' and it contains a column named 'class'

when I execute the following line I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
print("Unique values in the Class column:", dataset.class.unique())
```

It works for another column names but not working with 'class'

How to use a keyword as column name in pandas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in python. A rule of thumb: whenever you're dealing with  column names that *cannot* be used as valid variable names in python, you must use the bracket notation to access: `dataset['class'].unique()`.

There are, of course, exceptions here, but they work against your favour. For example, `min`/`max` is a valid variable name in python (even though it shadows builtins). In the case of pandas, however, you cannot refer to such a named column using the Attribute Access notation. There are more such exceptions, they're enumerated in the documentation.

A good place to begin with further reading is the documentation on [Attribute Access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access). Specifically, the red *Warning* box), which I'm adding here for posterity:

> - You can use this access only if the index element is a valid Python
>   identifier, e.g. `s.1` is not allowed. See here for an explanation of
>   valid identifiers.
> - The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing
>   method name, e.g. `s.min` is not allowed, but `s['min']` is possible.
> - Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with
>   any of the following list: `index, major_axis, minor_axis, items`.
> - In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. `s['1']`,
>   `s['min']`, and `s['index']` will access the corresponding element or
>   column.

Answer (score 0):

class is reserved word.
You can do as dataset['class'].unique()